# how to correctly call a function using foreach in spark using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

i have loaded my edge list in graphX and made a structure to save nodes ID and their neighbors using this code:

```
val nodes_neighbors: VertexRDD[Array[VertexId]] = graph.collectNeighborIds(EdgeDirection.Either).cache()
```

i wrote a simple function to get nodes ID and print their neighbors. after solving my problem i will extend the function. the simple function is as below:

```
def keyNodes_neighbors(vertex: VertexId,neighbors_list:VertexRDD[Array[VertexId]] ) = {

     neighbors_list.filter(x=>x._1==vertex).foreach(x=>print(x._2.foreach(println)))

   }
```

i have another structure that it keep nodes ID and their weight as its property: `important_nodes: RDD[(VertexId, Float)]`

now i want to call the `keyNodes_neighbors` function for each of these nodes in `important_nodes` RDD.

`important_nodes.keys.foreach(i=>keyNodes_neighbors(i,all_neighbors))`

when i do the above code i get some errors. but when i test this code `nodes_neighbors.filter(x=>x._1==1).foreach(x=>print(x._2.foreach(println)))` for a random node, for example node ID=1, i get neighbors of that node. please help me with this problem.

Comment: You can not use and RDD inside a function of another RDD.

Comment: then whats should i do to solve this problem?can you please explain?

Comment: You would need to refactor your code, but I am bad a **Spark** so I do not have a precise idea of how to do it. Just wanted to point the error.